# Can I use setSeed() to assign a particular sequence in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, random-seed

I'm new to programming and I'm teaching myself Java.

Currently I'm studying Ggraphics. Here is what I want to accomplish.
I want to make 5 rows of 10 bricks lined up horizontally. I want to assign a different color for each row. (So there is a sequence of color--RED, YELLOW, GREEN) I am wondering if I could use setColor(nextColor()) and setSeed() to assign the particular sequence of color.

`setColor()` and `nextColor()` are methods from [this package](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GOval.html).
`setSeed` is a method from [this package](http://nifty.stanford.edu/2005/GridPlotter/GridPkgClassDocumentation/edu/kzoo/util/RandNumGenerator.html#setSeed%28long%29).

I want to know if anyone has an idea on how I can use `setSeed()` to help me create a sequence which could do something like this:

`Red Red Red Red
Yel Yel Yel Yel
Grn Grn Grn Grn
Red Red Red Red <- sequence restarts here
Yel Yel Yel Yel`

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? If not how didn't it do what you wanted?

Comment: What are `setColor`, `nextColor` and `setSeed`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: (Added tags. Corrected grammar. Removed thanks.) Your question is unclear. Please edit it: Explain exactly what you are doing, as if we don't know your context, because we don't. (Eg: What do you expect us to understand from "assign a particular sequence"? What/where is "Ggraphics"? Are you trying to say that you want to use class Random? Which one?) Please show what code you have so far. Please incorporate the other comments. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).